# Why is my Derby database ping failing with a ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-3, classnotfoundexception

I have started my Derby database server successfully with `./asadmin start-database`, but when I clicked on a database to connect, it couldn't.  When I pinged it, it failed.

Has anyone experienced this error before and how have they solved it?

Exception log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.internal.derby.connection.DerbyEmbeddedJDBCConnection.createConnection(DerbyEmbeddedJDBCConnection.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.internal.derby.connection.DerbyJDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(DerbyJDBCConnectionFactory.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: you should added the jar of derby jdbc driver in you classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem connecting to MS SQL server.  I found something on another site that pointed me in the right direction.  Go to the database connection then edit the driver details.  Then go to the Properties tab.  In here make sure it has the right server name, database name, and user login and password.  Here is the site where I found this -> http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/39959/

Comment: Your answer addresses what appears to be a different situation. His problem is likely a bad classpath. Your problem was connectivity and configuration.

Comment: I see what you mean about the class path errors.  But what threw me was the ping error he is getting which is what I was getting too.  Originally I thought my problem was a class path one but turned out it was instead a connection one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I get it to work by going over through the next steps... It might help...

1. From the connection profile "GlassFishSampleDB" selected
2. I clicked on "Edit Drive definition" (Icon looks like Triangle shape)
3. On this page I seen a message Under "Provide Drive Details" showing a path to the file and says it is not found.
4. From the tabs I selected JAR List and hit button "Edit JAR/ZIP"
5. Then I go to the path location and select the ".....\..\glassfish4\javadb\lib\derbyclient.jar"